# Sending mail with python - how to set Return-Path that is different from 'From' address

Tags: python, smtp, email-bounces, lamson

What im trying to do is to set up smail mail server with lamson (lamsonproject.org). Its working very well, but i have problem with setting return path and for that reason, bounces are going to 'From' address and therefore not reaching my mail server.

Lamson uses pythons smtplib to send mails out.

The "talk" between my project and my smtp server goes like that:

```
send: 'ehlo xxx.mydomiain.com\r\n'
reply: '250-smtp.smtpserver.com\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 20000000\r\n'
reply: '250-VRFY\r\n'
reply: '250-ETRN\r\n'
reply: '250-STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: '250-XVERP\r\n'
reply: '250 8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: smtp.smtpserver.com
PIPELINING
SIZE 20000000
VRFY
ETRN
STARTTLS
XVERP
8BITMIME
send: u'mail FROM:<me@myotherdomain.com> size=352\r\n'
reply: '250 Ok\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: Ok
send: u'rcpt TO:<pleasebouncethis@myotherdomain.com>\r\n'
reply: '250 Ok\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: Ok
send: 'data\r\n'
reply: '354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>\r\n'
reply: retcode (354); Msg: End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
data: (354, 'End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>')
send: 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nTo: pleasebouncethis@myotherdomain.com\r\nSubject: Testing bounces\r\nSender: MAILER-DAEMON@mydomiain.com\r\nReturn-Path: MAILER-DAEMON@mydomain.com\r\nReply-To: MAILER-DAEMON@mydomain.com\r\nMessage-Id: 377b8dcdf661810d3dc73a4a01fe23b3\r\nFrom: me@myotherdomain.com\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\nc2RmZ2TDpGfDpGRsZsOkZ2xkZmc=\r\n.\r\n'
reply: '250 Ok: queued as E635D157D3\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: Ok: queued as E635D157D3
data: (250, 'Ok: queued as E635D157D3')
send: 'quit\r\n'
reply: '221 Bye\r\n'
reply: retcode (221); Msg: Bye
Done
```

so i can see, that the Return-Path is indeed in headers.

While looking for an answer i found this :
[Setting Return-Path with Python sendmail for a MIME message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337055/setting-return-path-with-python-sendmail-for-a-mime-message)

Last comment in the answer is:
Errors/bounces/etc. should go to the Envelope sender, not the address in From:.

When looking up Envelope sender and how to specify, i came across this wiki article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_address

This lists another possible header parameters like:
return path, reverse path, envelope from, envelope sender, MAIL FROM, 2821-FROM, return address, From_, Errors-to.

I put all those into mail headers and - Voila - It worked.

My question is now - Do i really have to ALWAYS list so many possible options for return path in mail headers? Have the mail servers been configured to accept one or two of those parameters now? Are there better ways to make sure, that mail is returned to my mail server, when it bounces?

Alan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are *sending* mail then you don't need to set any of those headers; the correct place for the envelope sender is in the `MAIL FROM:` command, so in your case:

```
MAIL FROM:<MAILER-DAEMON@mydomain.com>
```

Since this command is part of the SMTP protocol rather than the message itself, the *recipient* mail server adds a Return-Path header for the benefit of filters or other downstream processing where the original SMTP envelope is unavailable. See [RFC2821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821.html#page-50):

> When the delivery SMTP server makes the "final delivery" of a
> message, it inserts a return-path line at the beginning of the mail
> data.  This use of return-path is required; mail systems MUST support
> it.  The return-path line preserves the information in the
> <reverse-path> from the MAIL command.

Comment: After this long day of investigating this, my brain is somewhat fried. Let me get this straight - you're telling me that instead of setting those headers, i should use MAIL FROM command when sending mail. But since pythons smtplib is used to send mail out, and since that lamson is using that smtplib, i think i cant affect, which commands are sent to server by smtplib. Without rewriting lamson, anyway. Thats as far as i understand. Correct?

Comment: Anyway, MAIL FROM command is sent to server - you can see it in my log transcript. aint that the same command you refer to. My whole problem comes from that MAIL FROM address must be different from the actual address where the mails should go to.

Comment: Yes, it's the same command. If you're relaying the mail via Lamson's `relay.deliver(message, to, from)` function then just change the value of `to`, since this is what ends up in the `MAIL FROM` command.

Comment: If not then you might want to expand on how you're using Lamson, i.e. how the message originates and how you're sending it out to the other SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

The `from_addr` you use in the `sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, msg, mail_options=[], rcpt_options=[])` function will be the one the one that get's set as the `Return-Path`.

The `msg` you send with the function can contain a different `From:` header that's the normal from address people will see when they open the email.

You can see this in the [smtplib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail).
Quoting the note there:

> The from_addr and to_addrs parameters are used to construct the message envelope used by the transport agents. sendmail does not modify the message headers in any way.